# What is the most advanced Javascript 3D library for the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am looking for a 3D library similar to something like the Away3D project (flash) in javascript.
Particularily I need the following:

- Cameras (with pan tilt etc) preferably with options for smooth movement like the Away3d Hovercam
- 3D text (proper 3D models, not just a drop shadow)
- Meshes, textures etc
- A collection of primitives like triangles along with objects such as spheres.
- Lighting
- Support for IE (so possibly something that renders WebGL for Chrome then switches to something worse for IE)
- Preferably open source but commercial would be fine at a good price.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open source doesn't mean it is not commercial. It means open source.

Comment: You can try [Phoria.js](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used to code some simple demos using `Three.js` and I highly recommend it. You may checkout its homepage and some demos at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

FYI, there's a wiki page for various Javascript game engines where you may find some nice projects: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

and a wiki page for 3D engines: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/WebGL