# How are the ships drawn on the eve online website?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was wondering how are the ships drawn from here: http://www.eveonline.com/universe/spaceships/

I can see they use canvas, but is there any js framework or something to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: If it's Javascript and HTML, you can just view their source, you know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what somebody else is doing

Comment: I've never been so conflicted about a vote. On the one hand, it's clearly off-topic. On the other hand, I'm really curious to know more about it....

Comment: Ok, here's what I found in their source: http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/shipviewer/ccp.shipviewer-0.989.min.js. It also looks like they're pulling in assets from http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/shipviewer/assets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/shipviewer/ccp.shipviewer-0.989.min.js), it looks like they are using WebGL.
Here's a popular 3D JS framework to start looking at:  http://threejs.org/

Related resources here,  [What is the most advanced Javascript 3D library for the HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702880/what-is-the-most-advanced-javascript-3d-library-for-the-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

It uses a [`canvas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) and [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

From the article, WebGL is...

> a JavaScript API for rendering interactive 3D graphics and 2D
>   graphics within any compatible web browser without the use of
>   plug-ins. WebGL is integrated completely into all the web standards of
>   the browser allowing GPU accelerated usage of physics and image
>   processing and effects as part of the web page canvas. WebGL elements
>   can be mixed with other HTML elements and composited with other parts
>   of the page or page background. WebGL programs consist of control
>   code written in JavaScript and shader code that is executed on a
>   computer's Graphics Processing Unit (GPU). WebGL is designed and
>   maintained by the non-profit Khronos Group.

As far as how to create these graphics:

> WebGL scenes can be created without programming using a content
>   creation tool such as Blender, CopperCube or Autodesk Maya. The scenes
>   are then exported to WebGL. There are also services to publish
>   interactive 3D content online using WebGL.

For a specific look at the JS they used, take a look at this prettified version of the source:

http://pastebin.com/w5Rc8ueD

Comment: Nice,  I didn't know you could un-minify the source.  What tool did you use for that?

Comment: @Kal_Torak There's a great site called: http://jsbeautifier.org/. It can even help de-obfuscate js sometimes.